# AWS Route53 and Elastic Load Balancers equivalent on the new Azure IaaS cloud

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, high-availability

We are on the process of choosing a Cloud provider to run our VMs, and we would like to better understand the differences between AWS and the new Azure.

Does anyone know if Azure Cloud (IaaS) have an equivalent for the AWS Route53 and Elastic Load Balancer?
If it has, how does it work? Do they also have several different zones across the globe capable of providing High-Availability with minimum impact on the latency?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part yes, there is equivalence.  Windows Azure has always had a load balancer on any external endpoint (exposed over the VIP).  It is not a super programmable firewall at this point (you cannot do more than simply remove yourself from rotation), but it works very well for web farm scenarios.

Cloud Traffic Manager works very well for geo-locating your services in Windows Azure.  Just deploy your service in multiple datacenters, configure a few settings in traffic manager, and you are done.  Most folks use it for 'best performance' (i.e. closest DC to customer), but also you can use it for 'failover'.

In terms of DNS, there is no equivalent service today for handling external DNS names.  You handle DNS today with your own servers.  That is one point where AWS is ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft doesn't have a DNS service like Route53. But does support common DNS operations such as c-name routing/forwarding to various Windows Azure services. As for zones, there are currently 8 locations that MSFT offers for hosting of Windows Azure, 2 in Europe, 2 in Asia, 4 in the US, and Fujistsu offers hosting of some Windows Azure services in Japan. With the possible exception of Fujitsu (I don't know the details of their SLA), all Windows Azure Services are at least 99.9% (the definition of "highly available" is subjective). Additionally, Microsoft has the Content Delivery Network with more than 24 nodes spread across the globe to help speed delivery and reduce the latency of content being delivered to almost any geography.